# DLL not found if placed outside System32

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and added a reference to an external library with IDL and DLL file.

The program is finding correctly the DLL, if I copy it manually into C:\Windows\System32

But if I move the DLL somewhere else, even at the same place of the .exe file or in the path, the execution return this error code : (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.

I even tried to set the Environment Path=C:\MyPath;%Path% into Visual Studio, but this doesn't help. Any idea what could be the issue ? Did I missed something ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=0xc0000135+dependent+dll+was+not+found -- there's a bunch of similar errors reported. One thing in short: It could be a dependency of your DLL, use `depends.exe` to find out.

Comment: If you used IDL then it is likely that this library is implemented as a COM server.  Which normally uses registration to help the OS to find the DLL, typically done by an installer or Regsvr32.exe.  Moving the DLL after registration causes this error.  Run regsvr32.exe again to update the registry, asking the library owner for the proper procedure is best.